# Is there a default ordered datastructure in .net that that supports custom comparison function?

Tags: .net, data-structures

I want to sort objects according to values of their parameters which specify priority of processing.

HashSet and OrderedDictionary use IEqualityComparer only for checking equality.

Comment: What kind of data structure? Keyed? and sorted by what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the ordered containers from the BCL can accept a custom `IComparer<T>` that allows you to specify how their contents should be ordered ([for example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx), `SortedList<T>`).

`HashSet` is an *unordered* container so it has no place in this discussion and `SortedDictionary` [*does* accept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bkw66bd.aspx) an `IComparer<TKey>`.

Comment: HashSet does accept IEqualityComparer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346458%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @user2136963: `IEqualityComparer<T>` and `IComparer<T>` are very different things. The former can only tell you if two objects are equal, while the latter also tells you which one is "smaller" (if any).